# How to Copy text from an IE page and paste it in excel

Tags: html, excel, vba

> From the IE web page (HTML) I want to copy the start year ,end year and user ID to the excel.Assest me to create the VBA to get the data.

```html
<table class="tableFormat">
      <tbody><tr style="background-color: rgb(173, 165, 189);">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>

        <th class="center">Model Year </th>
        <th class="center">Status </th>
        <th class="center">Effective Date </th>
        <th class="center">Ineffective Date </th>
        <th class="center">Rev. </th>
        <th class="center">User Id </th>
        <th class="center">Date </th>
    
        
    </tr>

    <tr id="tr0" bgcolor="silver">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(0)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2017&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr1">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(1)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2016&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr2">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(2)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2015&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr3">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(3)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2014&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr4">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(4)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2013&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr5">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(5)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2012&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr6">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(6)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2011&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr7">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(7)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2010&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr8">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(8)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2009&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr9">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(9)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2008&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>

    <tr id="tr10">
        <td>
            <input name="rdOper" onclick="return radio_onclick(10)" type="radio"> 
        </td>
        
        <td class="center">2007&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">P&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">01-APR-2021&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-DEC-9999&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">C&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">GSMITH53&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="center">31-MAR-2021</td>
        

    </tr>


</tbody></table>
```

---

```
Sub Status_and__Date_Change()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    Dim SHELL_OBJECT
    SHELL_OBJECT = "WScript.Shell"
    Set objShell = CreateObject(SHELL_OBJECT)

    IE.Visible = True

    ' Set numrows = number of rows of APA to APA.
    NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    For intRow = 3 To NumRows

        'navigate URL
        IE.navigate "https://www.gslts.ford.com/TimeStudy/StatusAndDates.asp?CSTK=Y"

        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        Set Doc = IE.document
        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
        Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        Doc.getElementsByName("rdOper")(0).Click

        Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("J" & intRow).Value = IE.Doc.getElementsByClassName("center")(4).innerHTML

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("I" & intRow).Value = "Changed"
    Next

End Sub
```

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with more info on what isn't working. What is happening? Any error messages?

Comment: When I run your code it requires a login. I am not asking you to share login details (please don't), but it does mean I can't run and see if I get same output as your image. Where is `Rev.` coming from?  To insert your code correctly please highlight all your code then press Ctrl + K to indent it properly. I see this is a recurring problem you have had. I have formatted and indented your code here.

Comment: <table class="tableFormat">
      <tbody><tr style="background-color: rgb(173, 165, 189);">
        <th>&nbsp;</th>

        <th class="center">Model Year </th>
        <th class="center">Status </th>
        <th class="center">Effective Date </th>
        <th class="center">Ineffective Date </th>
        <th class="center">Rev. </th>
        <th class="center">User Id </th>
        <th class="center">Date </th>   "Rev. is coming from this HTML. Since i am using "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("J" & intRow).Value = IE.Doc.getElementsByClassName("center")(4).innerHTML"

Comment: in the first image, you can find the "rev." in the heading. In the following  if I give 5 instead of 4 the result will be "User Id"               
"ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("J" & intRow).Value = IE.Doc.getElementsByClassName("center")(4).innerHTML